# How to send data to a Web app in Flutter?

Tags: post, flutter-web

I have a desktop app that sends an email with a link which the user clicks on to be taken to the web app. There are some necessary data embedded in the link URL which the web app extracts and uses.

Over time this data has grown quite large and I'm worried it might start to cause problems with various browsers/email clients.

Is there a better way of doing it? I thought about something similar to PHP's $POST but all the results I found were for making requests *from* the web app.

Comment: What example could I write? The app works fine; the problem is that the documentation for Flutter Web is almost non-existent. Just lists of classes and return types. After hours of searching I posted the question hoping to get an answer like: "It's impossible", or "Use Window.NavigationEvent".

Comment: Fair enough, it was flagged for review,